# Cuda dpkg error on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: nvidia, dpkg, cuda, error-handling

I am trying to install cuda onto ubuntu 22.04 LTS but every time I get to the dpkg command it doesn't work, claiming its an unknown option, I have no idea if I'm putting the wrong command in but here is the code

```
nerdsrepublic@nerd:~$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
--2022-11-23 11:36:56--  https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu2204/x86_64/cuda-ubuntu2204.pin
Resolving developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)... 152.195.19.142
Connecting to developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)|152.195.19.142|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 190 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: ‘cuda-ubuntu2204.pin’

cuda-ubuntu2204.pin 100%[===================>]     190  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2022-11-23 11:36:57 (8.11 MB/s) - ‘cuda-ubuntu2204.pin’ saved [190/190]

nerdsrepublic@nerd:~$ sudo mv cuda-ubuntu2204.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
nerdsrepublic@nerd:~$ wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb
--2022-11-23 11:37:14--  https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.8.0/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb
Resolving developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)... 152.195.19.142
Connecting to developer.download.nvidia.com (developer.download.nvidia.com)|152.195.19.142|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3181904146 (3.0G) [application/x-deb]
Saving to: ‘cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb’

cuda-repo-ubuntu220 100%[===================>]   2.96G  11.2MB/s    in 4m 32s  

2022-11-23 11:41:46 (11.2 MB/s) - ‘cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb’ saved [3181904146/3181904146]

nerdsrepublic@nerd:~$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb
dpkg: error: unknown option -�

Type dpkg --help for help about installing and deinstalling packages [*];
Use 'apt' or 'aptitude' for user-friendly package management;
Type dpkg -Dhelp for a list of dpkg debug flag values;
Type dpkg --force-help for a list of forcing options;
Type dpkg-deb --help for help about manipulating *.deb files;

Options marked [*] produce a lot of output - pipe it through 'less' or 'more' !
nerdsrepublic@nerd:~$
```

**Here is the cuda installation guide I am following with the step that is having issue highlighted:**

[image: Cuda instructions]

Please help me figure out what I am doing wrong,I don't use dpkg for many things and need help trying to install Cuda.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this problem too and here is the solution I've found: You just need to type a new `-i` and replace the `-i` in this command `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu2204-11-8-local_11.8.0-520.61.05-1_amd64.deb`, then the problem would be solved.

Comment: Your answer is somewhat confusing: "type new -i and replace -i".  Can you rephrase this to provide more clarity for your audience?

Answer (score 0):

You can type this command manually instead of copying it from website. I was getting same error, but then I just typed the command manually and it worked.